# ¿Cómo puedo agregar más de un puntero en google maps, en un ejemplo que usa geolocalización?

Tags: javascript, html

Aquí esta mi código espero me puedan apoyar.

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyBrcs5yH0nw2VdRQ2dL5btYv1h0E1meC4Q"></script>
<script>
    function findMe(){
        var output = document.getElementById('map');

        // Verificar si soporta geolocalizacion
        if (navigator.geolocation) {
            output.innerHTML = "<p>Tu navegador soporta Geolocalizacion</p>";
        }else{
            output.innerHTML = "<p>Tu navegador no soporta Geolocalizacion</p>";
        }

        //Obtenemos latitud y longitud
        function localizacion(posicion){

            var latitude = posicion.coords.latitude;
            var longitude = posicion.coords.longitude;

            var imgURL = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center="+latitude+","+longitude+"&size=600x300&markers=color:red%7C"+latitude+","+longitude+"&key=AIzaSyBrcs5yH0nw2VdRQ2dL5btYv1h0E1meC4Q";

            output.innerHTML ="<img src='"+imgURL+"'>";



        }

        function error(){
            output.innerHTML = "<p>No se pudo obtener tu ubicación</p>";

        }

        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(localizacion,error);

    }


</script>
```

Comment: Hola **sarai guido** te e dejado un ejemplo practico, entiende el código, al parecer stackoverflow bloquea la geolocalizacion así que te aconsejo que lo copies y lo pruebes. saludos

Answer (score 0):

Debes poner agregar `Markers` en la `uri` de `googleMaps`
Con el formato

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center="+latitude+","+longitude+"&size=600x300" + 
           "&markers=color:red%7C"+latitude+","+longitude+
           "&markers=color:blue%7C"+secondLatitude+","+secondLong+
           "&key=AIzaSyBrcs5yH0nw2VdRQ2dL5btYv1h0E1meC4Q
```

El segundo `Marker` se pondrá con las variables `secondLatitude` y `secondLong`

```
<script>

        function localizacion(posicion){
        var secondLatitude = -34.6112011;
        var secondLong = -58.37840600000011;
            var output = document.getElementById('map');
            var latitude = posicion.coords.latitude;
            var longitude = posicion.coords.longitude;
            var imgURL = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center="+latitude+","+longitude+"&size=600x300" + 
               "&markers=color:red%7C"+latitude+","+longitude+
               "&markers=color:blue%7C"+secondLatitude+","+secondLong+
               "&key=AIzaSyBrcs5yH0nw2VdRQ2dL5btYv1h0E1meC4Q";
            output.innerHTML ="<img src='"+imgURL+"'>";
        }
       function findMe(){
          // Verificar si soporta geolocalizacion
          var output = document.getElementById('map');
          if (navigator.geolocation) {
              output.innerHTML = "<p>Tu navegador soporta Geolocalizacion</p>";
          }else{
              output.innerHTML = "<p>Tu navegador no soporta Geolocalizacion</p>";
          }
        }
        function error(){
            var output = document.getElementById('map');
            output.innerHTML = "<p>No se pudo obtener tu ubicación</p>";
        }
 navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(localizacion,error);



</script>
```

Referencia: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/maps-static/intro

Comment: Tome código del tuyo y funciona muy bien gracias

Comment: Perfecto, en caso que sea la respuesta a tu pregunta marcarla como tal.

Answer (score 0):

Utilizando la función `google.maps.Marker()` puedes asignar los marcadores que gustes. En este caso puedes realizar una función para que te agregue los marcadores que necesites, anexo un ejemplo:

```
function appendMarker(map, latitude, longitude, text) {
    var pos = {lat: latitude, lng: longitude};
    var markerOption = {
      position: pos,
      map: map,
      title: text || 'Hello World!'
    };
    return new google.maps.Marker(markerOption);
  }

// Verificar si soporta geolocalización
if (navigator.geolocation) {
  navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
    var pos = {
      lat: position.coords.latitude,
      lng: position.coords.longitude
    };

    infoWindow.setPosition(pos);
    infoWindow.setContent('Your Location.');
    map.setCenter(pos);

    //Aquí agregamos los marcadores que necesitamos, mandamos a llamar la función con sus respectivos parámetros.
    var markerOp = appendMarker(map, position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude, 'Hello');
    var markerOp2 = appendMarker(map, position.coords.latitude + 0.005, position.coords.longitude + 0.005, 'Hello');

  }, function() {
    handleLocationError(true, infoWindow, map.getCenter());
  });
```

Espero y te ayude. Saludos.

Comment: Gracias me funcionó el ejemplo

Comment: Un gusto ayudarte compañero, te agradecería si colocas la respuesta como correcta en caso de que haya sido de tu utilidad. Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Para añadir **Marker** a tu mapa tienes que trabajar **object() Map API**. En este pequeño ejemplo trabajo con un **array**, el cual almacena la posición que el **evento click()** me da, posterior lo pongo en el mapa, puse una **función de eliminar marker** en caso te sirva. Espero te ayude :)

[En este sitio encontraras mas información con ejemplos](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/markers)

```js
// variables globales
 var map;
    var markers = [];
    
 function myMap() {
     if (navigator.geolocation) {
         navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition, showError);
     } 
        else { 
         alert("La Geolocalizacion no es soportado por este Browser.");
     }

  function showPosition(position) 
        {        
          //Obtenemos la ubicacion
          var Lat = position.coords.latitude;
          var Lng = position.coords.longitude;         
    var tuGeoLoca = {lat: Lat, lng: Lng};
    
          //Crea el objet map
          map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
            zoom: 10,
            center: tuGeoLoca,
            mapTypeId: 'terrain'
          });
          setTimeout(function(){map.setZoom(17)}, 3000);

          // Este evento va a esperar un click en el mapa y añadira un Marker().
          map.addListener('click', function(event) {
            addMarker(event.latLng);
          });

          // Añade un Marker en el centro del mapa, en este caso tu Geo....
          addMarker(tuGeoLoca);
       }


        // Añade marker en el Mapa and lo carga en el array.
        function addMarker(location) {
          var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: location,
            map: map
          });
          markers.push(marker);
        }
     
        // Borrar todos los marker del mapa y vacia el array.
        function borrarMarkers(){
          for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
            markers[i].setMap(null);
          }
          markers = [];
        }
  }

    //esto es si no se acepto o si hubo un error con la geolocalizacion
    function showError(error) {
        switch(error.code) {
            case error.PERMISSION_DENIED:
                alert( "Usted a negado la Geolocalizacion.");
                break;
            case error.POSITION_UNAVAILABLE:
                alert( "Location informacion corrupta.");
                break;
            case error.TIMEOUT:
                alert( "Tiempo de espera exedido.");
                break;
            case error.UNKNOWN_ERROR:
                alert( "Ocurrio un error.");
                break;
        }
    }
```

```css
#map{
width:500px;height:400px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<!--<style> Aqui va el css
</style>-->
<div id="map"></div>
<div id="floating-panel">
    <input onclick="borrarMarkers();" type=button value="Borrar Markers">
</div>
<!-- Aqui va el codigo JavaScript
<script> 
</script>
-->
<script async defer
    src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyBrcs5yH0nw2VdRQ2dL5btYv1h0E1meC4Q&callback=myMap">
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por la ayuda todas funcionan al 100